# MySql Workbench Insert Template Parameters Shortcut

Tags: mysql-workbench

So in SSMS I can use the shortcut [ctrl + shift + M] to populate these template placeholders. Here is an example of insert into table for ssms:

[image: Example of SSMS Insert Template Parameters]

In MySQL Workbench, when I send an insert statement to the sql editor (just like ssms), I see the same template placeholders but I can't figure out how to edit them as fast as ssms.  Does this feature exist in MySQL Workbench?  For reference, here is a screenshot of the template placeholders in MySQL workbench:

[image: MySQL Workbench insert template parameters]